# Loop posts without any taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, loop

I've grouped my pages by some custom taxonomy. But I need to care about those without any taxonomy set. My code is:

```
$page_groups = get_terms('page_group'); //get all existing page groups
foreach ($page_groups as $page_group) { //for every of them
    $group_name = $page_group->name;    //get group name
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'page_group' => $group_name ) );    //and loop for all pages from that category

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        //main stuff here

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();   //reset loop
    rewind_posts();     //and rewind posts
} // End foreach $page_groups ?>
```

It works cool, but after that loop I want to display all the pages that has no 'page_group' taxonomy - only those. I've tried to query without taxonomy but it loops all the pages.

Comment: What is `page_group`? Not seeing that as an available option in [`WP Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). `get_terms()` can retrieve the taxonomy by using `$page_group->taxonomy` which you could set in `WP_Query`

Comment: page group is custom taxonomy. the code i've pasted is working ok and it loops all groups and all posts of all grops. I need another loop that loops only posts that HAS ANY post_group taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to give a value of "none" to your posts without any post group, similarly as you have "uncategorized" posts in WP Categories.

Alternatively… I haven't checked it, but why don't you try to make another `WP_QUERY` like this:

```
new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'page_group' => '' ) )
```